# Getting function names from php file with preg_match_all

Tags: php

I have a file **test.php**:

```
public function editAction() {
   //...
}  

public function editGroupAction() {
   //...
}
```

This is my code:

```
$source = "test.php";
$fh = fopen($source,'r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
   preg_match_all('/function(.*?)Action()/', $line, $matches);
   var_dump($matches);
}
```

I want to get the functions that end with `Action`, but the result is empty. How do I get a result like this:

```
edit
editGroup
```

Comment: Result is not empty, see here : https://eval.in/612829  ---  EDIT : Too slow, guess @FirstOne deserves his nickname.

Comment: As for the question: make sure your code is the same as the one you posted.

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll still have a space at the beginning of your outputs, you should escape that as well.

Comment: I had edit question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
$fileName = 'test.php';
$fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);
preg_match_all('/function(.*?)Action()/', $fileContent, $matches);
$functions = $matches[1];
```

Result (`$functions`):

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  edit
    [1] =>  editGroup
)
```

---

---

***Following is your code with some changes...***

First, check if anything was found, if so, add that to an array. Here is the working code:

```
$source = "test.php";
$fh = fopen($source,'r');
$m = array();
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    if(preg_match_all('/function(.*?)Action()/', $line, $matches)){
        $m[] = $matches[1][0];
    }
}
```

Result (`$m`):

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  edit
    [1] =>  editGroup
)
```

---

Since [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) *returns the number of full pattern matches*, you can use the return to check if anything was found. If you get a hit, add the wanted value to an array so you can get it later.

You were getting some empty results because not all lines will match ;)

---

**Sidenote:** As mentioned, you'll end up with something like `string(5) " edit"` (notice the **white space**). I don't know preg, so I can't fix it for you. What I can do is suggest you to change to `$functions = array_map('trim', $matches[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want, but you should escape parentheses in regexp.

So here's your code with minor modifications:

```
<?php
$content = "public function editAction() public function editGroupAction()";
preg_match_all('/function(.*?)Action\(\)/', $content, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

And yes, result is not empty :)